# ModRewrite: RewriteRule fails

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to redirect two requests but only one of them works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/\.]+)?$ cat.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/\.]+)?$ user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

domain.com/cat/something -> works

domain.com/user/12345 - > don't work ($_GET is empty)

It's very strange because the first (identically) rule works perfectly.

Maybe it's just because the second rule can't handle digits or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have options `MultiViews` turned on. Disable it by placing this line on top of `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: Yes! I understand now that the server sees /user and looks for a directory or a similar file (e.g. user.php). So it redirects directly to user.php without the $1 parameters. Another idea would be using **RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f and RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d**